# Access member of a iterator of a vector of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, unique-ptr

I have a vector:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyAbstract>> myList;
```

I want to access the member "id" in a loop and erase a specific item:

```
for (auto it = myList.begin(); it != myList.end();)
{
    if (it->id == 2)
    {
        it = myList.erase(it);
        break;
    }
    else
        ++it;
}
```

this line...

```
if (it->id == 2)
```

gives me an error:

> 'class std::unique_ptr' has no member named 'id'

This seems to work:

```
if (it->get()->id == 2)
```

I wonder why?! Here's the full code:
http://ideone.com/kFohfA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`it` is an iterator so `it->` attempts to access a member of the type stored in the vector(`std::unique_ptr<MyAbstract>`) not the `MyAbstract` the `std::unique_ptr` holds.  What you need to do is dereference the iterator to get the underlying `std::unique_ptr<MyAbstract>` and then you can access the member of `MyAbstract` with `->` like

```
(*it)->id
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it's because of the underlying type, but I thought the -> would magically point to the MyAbstract inside the unique_ptr so I would not have to use get().

Comment: @DoubleVoid If it did that then you would not be able to easily access the members of the `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

`*it` has type `std::unique_ptr<MyAbstract>`, of course it has no member named `id`.

So you have to get its "value", via `get ()`:

```
it->get()->id
```